# Vue2 lib for a tree table structure

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, tree, web-frontend, lib

Do you guys could suggest me a lib to build a treetable structure (e.g Windows Explorer Folders Structure) for Vue.js 2.5.16?

I'm absolutely newer with this technology, im not even a frontend developer, but in my job they asked me to do something similar to a tree table. I saw some interesting libs, but the most of them (99%), I couldn't even install because I have a lot of version compability problems, as our Vue version is pretty old.

Thankyou,

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.